# Is my unity component validation overkill?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity scripts need access to components they will be using, my solution here guarantees that a script will have a valid reference to a component it needs, but is this solution overkill, or hard to discern intention from?

Note: null coalescence operators would be cleaner but cannot be used for unity objects or components for terrible reasons.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]  // disallows deletion of component from editor
public class CubeControll : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null ? // if has component attached
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>() :  // assign referance
            gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>(); // else add new component
    }

    // start, update etc
}
```

This is a common situation, are there any general best practices to doing this?

Comment: is there any reason for not using the constructor to validate the `rigidbody`  ? so this way you can make it `readonly`.

Comment: @Heslacher, yes this is my real code... why do you say that? both branches of the `?:` operator return a `Rigidbody`... i'm not really sure what you mean?

Comment: @iSR5, are you familiar with Unity? This class inherits from monobehavior, you should never create a constructor for monobehavior derived objects

Comment: @Jake unfortunately no, that's why I asked you. But it's clear now.

Comment: Oh, you're right. sorry i don't know how that happened. I've corrected my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are calling `GetComponent<T>()` twice if the first call return a value != null.

Well, I would do this in a very simple way.

```
private void OnValidate()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if (rigidbody != null) { return; }
 
    rigidbody = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```